# Xcode/Instruments' "Gather leaked memory contents" gives me a useless hex-only dump

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

When using the "Gather Leaked Memory Contents" of the Leaks Instrument, it seems to give me only the hex contents of an object, rather than showing me the ASCII string beside it (like every other hex dump in the world ever). Worse still, this box is un-selectable, I cannot even copy it into a decent hex editor for a string view.

Is there a reason for such insanity?

Comment: Who can guess the reason, but I agree, this feature is much less helpful than it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to find the contents is by running leaks from the command-line.  Find the process name of your running app (you can use a tool such as from Activity Monitor or top), then in Terminal run:

```
leaks myprocessname
```

It should print out not only the address, size, and type of data, but the contents as well if it can.  You can also, of course, copy the result from there into whatever hex editor you fancy.

Comment: This is great, I just found that it can report even leaks from and iOS app running on simulator.

Answer (score -3):

Because the point of the Leaks instrument is to show you *where* things are being leaked, which is far more useful than *what*.  When you know where and when things are leaked, go back to Xcode, set breakpoints, and step through.  If *what's* being leaked is important to *why*, then you can see that in the debugger in real time, rather than in Instruments after the fact in aggregate.

Comment: Except when the *where* is deep inside Apple's code, and happens only sometimes, leaving the nearest stack frame that is your own code unhelpful.  This is happening to me with an NSXMLParser, and seeing the actual string it's leaking would be enormously helpful in narrowing down the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I am tracking down a potential leak of NSXMLParser data too, and it would sure be useful to see what was leaked.

Comment: Also when using dynamic libraries, the stack is not displayed, so the contents would be really useful...if only it could be deciphered to something useful.